# How can I call a function of a helper class in a view - Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel, date, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have a helper class **DateHelper**

[image]

I have one fn in there

```
public static function getAgo($date) {

    if ($date) {

        $ts = time() - strtotime(str_replace("-","/",$date));

        if($ts>31536000) $val = round($ts/31536000,0).' year';
        else if($ts>2419200) $val = round($ts/2419200,0).' month';
        else if($ts>604800) $val = round($ts/604800,0).' week';
        else if($ts>86400) $val = round($ts/86400,0).' day';
        else if($ts>3600) $val = round($ts/3600,0).' hour';
        else if($ts>60) $val = round($ts/60,0).' minute';
        else $val = $ts.' second';

        if($val>1) $val .= 's';

        return $val;


    }

}
```

I want to use it in my view like this

```
{{ DateHelper::getAgo($log->createdAt) }}
```

I kept getting

> Class 'DateHelper' not found (View: ...

I tried to include it on top of my `index.blade.php` like this

```
<?php use App\DateHelper; ?>
```

Can someone please help me ?

Comment: Why not just use inline namespacing? `{{ \App\DateHelper::getAgo(...) }}` And of course make sure that `DateHelper` is in the `App` namespace, has the correct classname, etc. Or, alternatively, define a function on your `$log` variable (if it's a model) that uses `DateHelper`, and call something like `$log->dateHelperFunction()`. Lots of options :)

Comment: This seems to work `{{ \App\DateHelper::getAgo(...) }}` - please answer it so others can also learned from you.

Comment: Or you can use the `diffForHumans()` method in the Carbon date library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a `use` statement doesn't work in the view, you can always use inline namespacing:

```
{{ \App\DateHelper::getAgo($log->created_at) }}
```

Ensure the class is in the correct namespace and has the correct class/filename and you should be good to go.

Comment: Aliasing is definitely a better option.

Comment: There's pros and cons to every approach. Single use; this is fine. Multiple use; go with aliasing. Concerned about IDE auto-complete/discovery, don't use aliasing, etc etc. That's why there's 2 answers here :) If you think aliasing is a better option, please upvote that one.

Answer (score 10):

You can add an alias in your `config/app.php`:

```
'aliases' => [
    // ...
    'DateHelper' => App\DateHelper::class,
],
```

Then in your view you can simply do:

```
{{ DateHelper::getAgo($log->created_at); }}
```

Comment: I was wondering how that worked. Definitely more useful for DRY principles if you need to use this helper multiple times.

Comment: @TimLewis I don't like aliases. It forces you to write/generate an IDE helper file if you actually want t o get any useful autocompletion out of your IDE

Comment: @apokryfos Hmm, interesting; hadn't thought of that, but it's definitely a valid concern. Duly noted. Personally, if I have a helper like this, I incorporate it into the model, like `public function getSomethingAttribute(){ return WhateverHelper::getSomething(); // or $this->whateverHelper->getSomething(); }`, so I haven't come across that issue.